# Show latest topic of subcategory SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make an category with subcategories which shows the latest topic from an subcategory.

However, something seems to be wrong in the database set-up.

Query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *
FROM categories
  LEFT JOIN subs ON subs.category_id = categories.id
  LEFT JOIN threads ON subs.category_id = threads.subcategory_id
WHERE threads.lastdate = 5 AND categories.id = subs.category_id AND subs.category_id = threads.subcategory_id AND
      threads.lastdate = threads.lastdate
GROUP BY threads.lastdate, categories.id ASC")
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `threads` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subcategory_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

subs:

```
    CREATE TABLE `subs` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `category_id` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )

 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Categories:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Hopes someone gets me out of fire.

TJ

Comment: What error do you get? Provide more info.

Comment: When I try creating an new thread in the database with lastdate '5' it still returns blank. I'll am not familiar with database structures, so maybe someone could give a look here who has the 
knowledge of it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve with that query, but you cannot use:

```
SELECT *
```

in conjunction with:

```
GROUP BY
```

*Either* change the select statement to:

```
SELECT threads.lastdate, categories.id
```

*or* delete the GROUP BY clause.

Gilad has tidied up a lot of your query, but he currently has a trailing AND at the end of his WHERE clause, and the aforementioned problem with GROUP BY and unfortunately I can't comment to let him know either.

**Edit** - Apparently you can use select * with group by in mysql...

Comment: The question - which frankly reads terribly - doesn't get downvoted, but my answer does (by some coward who doesn't explain why)? There's something bloody weird going on on this site.

Comment: It seems that I need to create an new SQL for my result I want. Accepted this as the answer since it does fit my requirements.